# Inject inline Mockito static methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am testing a class using JUnit4 and the target class uses a dependency static method to create an object, here is the relevant snippet of code from the target class:

```java
private static final Dependency DEPENDENCY_CLIENT = Dependency.getInstance();
```

I know that since version 3.4.0 of Mockito, there is the added ability to mock static methods, for example, I can do something like:

```java
try (MockedStatic<Dependency> mocked = mockStatic(Dependency.class)) {
  mocked.when(Dependency::getInstance).thenReturn(dependency);
  Dependency test = Dependency.getInstance();
  mocked.verify(Dependency::getInstance);
}
```

The `dependency` variable is just a simple mocked version of that class.

However, the class I want to test makes this call in its constructor, so is there a way where I can make my target class call the mocked `getInstance()` method during its initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what problem you are having. The code below works for me (I'm using JUnit 5, but that should make no difference)

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockEg {
    static class Dependency {
        public static Dependency getInstance() {
            return new Dependency();
        }
        public String getMessage() {
            return "I am not a mock";
        }
    }

    static class ClassToTest {

        private final Dependency dependency;
        public ClassToTest() {
            this.dependency = Dependency.getInstance();
        }

        public String getDependencyMessage() {
            return dependency.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        try (MockedStatic<Dependency> mocked = mockStatic(Dependency.class)) {
            Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
            when(dependency.getMessage()).thenReturn("I am a mock");
            mocked.when(Dependency::getInstance).thenReturn(dependency);
            ClassToTest c = new ClassToTest();
            assertThat(c.getDependencyMessage(), Matchers.is("I am a mock"));
            mocked.verify(Dependency::getInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

The right way to deal with this situation is to decouple your class from `static`s, by introducing an interface which you can mock:

```
    interface DependencyProvider {
        Dependency getDependency();
    }
    
    class ClassToTest2 {

        private final DependencyProvider dependencyProvider;
        public ClassToTest2(DependencyProvider dependencyProvider) {

            this.dependencyProvider = dependencyProvider;
        }

        public String getDependencyMessage() {
            return dependencyProvider.getDependency().getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have one minor difference in my code in which in my ClassToTest code would look like `private final Dependency dependency = Dependency.getInstance()`. Would that make a difference?

Comment: That doesn’t make a difference, as initialization of instance variables happens when the instance is created, ie the same time as the constructor